# How to prevent backend calls when opening static subpages?

Tags: angular, routes, timeout, jhipster

I have a project with a separated backend and frontend. Every time I try to open any other page than homepage, the JHipster fires and waits for two requests:

- `API_URL/jhb/management/info`
- `API_URL/jhb/api/account`

I have pages with static content that do not need connection with the server. Sometimes I am disconnected from the server, but the app *always* makes the calls, then waits and shows the page only after certain timeout (about 5 seconds). However, it does not wait when I try to open the homepage.

Is there a way to tell JHipster to skip or don't wait for these two backend calls, at least for certain routes?

I don't use microservices, just regular Tomcat deployment. JHipster version 6.5.1, Angular frontend

Comment: It will not make these calls if you tell the frontend on the client not to do them to the Spring framework on the server. Which type of frontend framework do you use, Angular, React, ...?

For Angular: look at the defined routes and redefine them regarding RouterModule.forRoot() - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60178766/7773582. But a standard JHipster-generated Angular frontend will only lazy load management and account - so if you don't click on a link to these components, there should be no delay...

Comment: ProfileService is called from NavbarComponent which is used on all pages for swagger and h2 database menus, if you don't use any of these you could probably get rid of all calls to /management/info. Same thing for  PageRibbonComponent, you could choose to get rid of it. For /api/account and AccountService it probably requires more work.

Comment: It's Angular frontend. Thanks for the comment, it's very informative! I may have found the cause of my problems: it's because these static pages have no real corresponding entities and were created using https://github.com/vivekmore/generator-jhipster-nav-element. 

After selecting a link (from navbar) only NavigationStart event is fired, RoutesRecognized, and then GuardsCheckStart, but it takes longer for GuardsCheckEnd. I think the routes are defined correctly in modules (using this generator), but somehow not linked somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem was to completely remove `canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService]` property from the `Route`. Then, the static page is, as wanted, visible immediately and for everyone.

It works, but what I was looking for was enabling (displaying) navbar/footer before (component's) route access was checked. Probably creating a nested component would do the trick. If you know a better solution /have better idea please share!